# Disprove "For all sets A and B, $A^c \cup B^c \subseteq (A \cup B)^c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I know that by De Morgan's law that it is false. But how to disprove it?

Comment: Find an example where this doesn't hold.

Comment: Have you tried any examples of $A, B$, in some small universal set (say, $\{1, 2\}$)?

Comment: A more interesting question is to ask "under what conditions is $A^c\cup B^c\subseteq (A\cup B)^c$".  Noting first that $(A\cup B)^c=A^c\cap B^c$ and that $A^c\cap B^c\subseteq A^c\cup B^c$, this would imply that $A^c\cup B^c=A^c\cap B^c$.  One can eventually conclude that you must have $A^c=B^c$ and thus $A=B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let the universal set be $\left\{ 0,1 \right\}$

Let $A=\left\{ 0\right\}$ and $B=\left\{ 1\right\}$

Verify that it works.

Comment: then $A^c$ and $B^c$ equals nothing?

Comment: @PhoxKiD One has $A^c=\{1\}$ and one has $B^c=\{0\}$.  The **intersection of** $A^c$ and $B^c$ is the emptyset.  (*it is unclear if you ask about $A^c$ individually followed by $B^c$ individually, or if you are asking about the intersection of $A^c$ and $B^c$.  try to be perfectly unambiguous with how you phrase things in mathematical contexts*)

Comment: to clarify $A^c \cup B^c = \{0,1\}$ and $(A \cup B)^c = \{\}$

Comment: Remark: $(A^c \cup B^c)$ and $(A \cup B)^c$ are not equal in general. Recall De Morgan's law.

Comment: Is $A^c \cup B^c = \{ 0, 1\} $?

Comment: yup, that is right.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a single counterexample.

Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{3,4,5\}$ and the universal set $U = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Then $A^c = \{4,5,6\}$ and $B^c = \{1,2,6\}$ and

$$A^c \cup B^c = \{1,2,4,5,6\} = (A \cap B)^c$$

but

$$(A \cup B)^c = \{6\} = A^c \cap B^c$$

and clearly $\{1,2,4,5,6\} \not\subseteq \{6\}$.

Comment: isn't A and B union, not intersection?

Comment: $\cup$ is union, $\cap$ is intersection

Comment: Ah i get it now, $A^c \cup B^c$ everything outside of the intersection but $(A \cup B)^c$ is everything outside of both sets

Answer (score 1):

Suppose x $\in$ $A^c \cup B^c$  assume wlog that x $\in$ $A^c$. Then x  $\in$ $A^c \cup B$, which implies x $\notin$   $(A \cup B)^c$